# iOS 7 Hardware Keyboard Events

Tags: events, keyboard, ios7

Now that we have iOS 7, Apple apparently has removed the option to receive keyboard notifications from `-sendEvent:`. This is a huge pain to people who are wanting to write something that captures all key events and sends it off to a remote computer, E.G. a VNC client. `UIKeyCommand` does not provide the functionality needed. There are many bug reports submitted to apple, but they will not listen. The bug report apple is closing all reports as a duplicate is rdar://14129420.

What is the best solution for this?

Answer (score 5):

I have at least been able to get these events back the private API way, however the keyup doesn't return any useful info such as the key that was released. Maybe this is something which can be pulled from `UIEvent`?

The code that's needed to be added is the following definition of `UIPhysicalKeyboardEvent`.

```
@interface PhysicalKeyboardEvent : UIEvent {//UIPhysicalButtonsEvent
    int _inputFlags;
    NSString *_modifiedInput;
    NSString *_unmodifiedInput;
    NSString *_shiftModifiedInput;
    NSString *_commandModifiedInput;
    NSString *_markedInput;
    long long _modifierFlags;
    NSString *_privateInput;
}
+ (id)_eventWithInput:(id)arg1 inputFlags:(int)arg2;
@property(retain, nonatomic) NSString *_privateInput; // @synthesize _privateInput;
@property(nonatomic) int _inputFlags; // @synthesize _inputFlags;
@property(nonatomic) long long _modifierFlags; // @synthesize _modifierFlags;
@property(retain, nonatomic) NSString *_markedInput; // @synthesize _markedInput;
@property(retain, nonatomic) NSString *_commandModifiedInput; // @synthesize _commandModifiedInput;
@property(retain, nonatomic) NSString *_shiftModifiedInput; // @synthesize _shiftModifiedInput;
@property(retain, nonatomic) NSString *_unmodifiedInput; // @synthesize _unmodifiedInput;
@property(retain, nonatomic) NSString *_modifiedInput; // @synthesize _modifiedInput;
@property(readonly, nonatomic) long long _gsModifierFlags;
- (void)_privatizeInput;
- (void)dealloc;
- (id)_cloneEvent;
- (_Bool)isEqual:(id)arg1;
- (_Bool)_matchesKeyCommand:(id)arg1;
//- (void)_setHIDEvent:(struct __IOHIDEvent *)arg1 keyboard:(struct __GSKeyboard *)arg2;
@property(readonly, nonatomic) long long _keyCode;
@property(readonly, nonatomic) _Bool _isKeyDown;
- (long long)type;
@end
```

To listen for events, use the following in a `UIResponder`. I am not sure if the responder needs to be key or not.

```
- (id)_keyCommandForEvent:(PhysicalKeyboardEvent *)event {
    //Some reason it gets called twice and it's not because of keyup. Keyup seems to not mention it's original key.
    [NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self];
    [self performSelector:@selector(processEvent:) withObject:event afterDelay:0];
    return [super _keyCommandForEvent:event];
}
- (void)processEvent:(PhysicalKeyboardEvent *)event {
    NSLog(@"%@", [event _unmodifiedInput]);
    NSLog(@"%d", [event _isKeyDown]);
    NSLog(@"%d", [event _inputFlags]);
    if ([event _isKeyDown] && [[event _unmodifiedInput] isEqualToString:@"s"] && [event _modifierFlags]==206158430208) {
        NSLog(@"Hello");
    }
}
```

I'm hoping that this code will at least be of some help to people who needs this. You can determine when the command key, option key, and control key is pressed using `_modifierFlags`. I haven't played around with it much, but seems to be an good way to get the events.

You could possibly borrow code from http://nacho4d-nacho4d.blogspot.com/2012/01/catching-keyboard-events-in-ios.html to improve. If anyone else finds a better way, please post them!

Since this is using private APIs, it might be better for you to wrap everything in `respondsToSelector`. Things such as `_unmodifiedInput`.

I am not sure if apple would accept an application that implements this, so use at your own risk.

Comment: I was looking info about UIKeyCommands and found myself in the link :P

Answer (score 4):

Override this method on UIApplication and have fun :)

```
- (void)handleKeyUIEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    size_t s = malloc_size((__bridge const void *)(event));
    NSLog(@"%s enter... %ld", __func__, s);
//    unsigned char *ptr = (unsigned char *)(__bridge void *)event;

    unsigned long *ptr = (unsigned long *)(__bridge void *)event;
//
//#define OFF_KEY_MASK 12
//#define OFF_KEY_SCANCODE 15
//#define OFF_KEY_CHAR 17

//    NSLog(@"type: %lx off: %d", *(ptr + 2), 2);
//    NSLog(@"MASK: %lx off: %d", *(ptr + OFF_KEY_MASK), OFF_KEY_MASK);
//    NSLog(@"SCAN: %lx off: %d", *(ptr + OFF_KEY_SCANCODE), OFF_KEY_SCANCODE);
//    NSLog(@"CHAR: %lx off: %d", *(ptr + OFF_KEY_CHAR), OFF_KEY_CHAR);

    NSLog(@"sizeof unsigned long: %lx", sizeof(unsigned long));

    for (int i = 0; i < s / 4; ++i) {
//        NSLog(@"... [%d] = %x", i, *(unsigned char *)(ptr + i));
        NSLog(@"... [%d] = %lx", i, *(unsigned long *)(ptr + i));
    }

#define OFF_DUMP 8

    unsigned long *dump = (unsigned long *) *(ptr + OFF_DUMP);
    s = malloc_size((const void *)*(ptr + OFF_DUMP));

    NSLog(@"... *[%d] size: %ld", OFF_DUMP, malloc_size((const void *)*(ptr + OFF_DUMP)));

    for (int i = 0; i < s / 4; ++i) {
        NSLog(@"..... [%d] = %lx", i, *(unsigned long *)(dump + i));
    }

    struct objc_super super_data = { self, [UIApplication class] };
    objc_msgSendSuper(&super_data, @selector(handleKeyUIEvent:), event);
//    [super handleKeyUIEvent:event];
}
```

Comment: How can I catch the touch events in the applications or in the homescreen?

Comment: I cannot fully understand your question about where you want to catch the touch events? If you meant on an application, there are public callbacks in UIView for touch events. But I don't think you can catch touch events that is on homescreen as it doesn't belong to your applications.

Comment: thank you for your answer.I mean catch the events in the jailbroken device.

Comment: handleKeyUIEvent is this allowed to use according to Apple, since it is a private method?